# Display font awesome in jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to display fontawesome icon if the user level is equal to 1 or etc.  How can i do that in this code. i got an error if i used if else statement inside. Thanks in advance!

```
 function show_product(){
        $.ajax({
            type  : 'ajax',
            url   : '<?php echo site_url('User/userData')?>',
            async : true,
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(data){
                var html = '';
                var i;
                var q = '';
                for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){


                    html += '<tr>'+
                            '<td>'+data[i].create_at+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+data[i].user_email+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+data[i].user_name+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+data[i].user_lastname+'</td>'+


                            '<td>'if (data[i].user_level == '1') {
                                ++
                            }'</td>'+



                            '<td>'+data[i].status+'</td>'+


                            '</tr>';
                }
                $('#show_data').html(html);
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: *i got an error* What error? Also, to add an icon, you just need to add fa's class. Just do `element.classList.toggle(className, condition)`

Comment: Please, consider to have a look at [this fantastic Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do using the ternary operator

```
function show_product(){
    $.ajax({
        type  : 'ajax',
        url   : '<?php echo site_url('User/userData')?>',
        async : true,
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(data){
            var html = '';
            var i;
            var q = '';
            for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){


                html += '<tr>'+
                        '<td>'+data[i].create_at+'</td>'+
                        '<td>'+data[i].user_email+'</td>'+
                        '<td>'+data[i].user_name+'</td>'+
                        '<td>'+data[i].user_lastname+'</td>'+


                        '<td>'+ data[i].user_level==1?'<i class="fa"></i>':'<i class="fa"></i></td>'
                        +
                        '<td>'+data[i].status+'</td>'+


                        '</tr>';
            }
            $('#show_data').html(html);
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely because the code don't know that you want run the `if` statement.

`'<td>'if (data[i].user_level == '1')` as you can see there is nothing separating the string `<td>` and the statement `if (data[i].user_level == '1')`

Try something like this:

```
function show_product() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'ajax',
    url: '<?php echo site_url('
    User / userData ')?>',
    async: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      var html = '';
      var i;
      var q = '';
      for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        html += '<tr>' +
          '<td>' + data[i].create_at + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + data[i].user_email + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + data[i].user_name + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + data[i].user_lastname + '</td>' +
          '<td>';

        if (data[i].user_level == '1') {
          html += '<i class="fas fas-user"></i>'
        }

        html += '</td>' +
          '<td>' + data[i].status + '</td>' +
          '</tr>';
      }
      $('#show_data').html(html);
    }
  });
}
```